# Google Authenticaion via Scrapy

Tags: scrapy, google-authentication

I was curious to know if google authetication could be achieved via `scrapy`. I tried with the following code snippet to achieve so.

**My code:**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request
import  logging
import json

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'hello'
    start_urls = ['https://accounts.google.com']
    handle_httpstatus_list = [404, 405]
    def parse(self, response):
        print('inside parse')
        print(response.url)
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'Email': 'abc@gmail.com'},
                    callback=self.log_password)]


    def log_password(self, response):
        print('inside log_password')
        print(response.url)
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'Passwd': 'password'},
                    callback=self.after_login)]

    def after_login(self, response):
        print('inside after_login')
        print(response.url)
        if "authentication failed" in response.body:
            self.log("Login failed", level=logging.ERROR)
            return
        # We've successfully authenticated, let's have some fun!
        else:
            print("Login Successful!!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36',
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.2,
        'HANDLE_HTTPSTATUS_ALL': True
    })

    process.crawl(LoginSpider)
    process.start()
```

But I'm getting following output when I run the script.

**Output**

```
2018-08-15 10:38:05 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: scrapybot) 

2018-08-15 10:38:05 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.3.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.7.0, Python 3.6.4 (default, Mar 22 2018, 14:05:57) - [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018), cryptography 2.3, Platform Darwin-15.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit 2018-08-15 10:38:05 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.2, 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'} 2018-08-15 10:38:05 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions: ['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',  'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',  'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',  'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats'] 

2018-08-15 10:38:05 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware', 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware', 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware', 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats'] 

2018-08-15 10:38:05 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware'] 

2018-08-15 10:38:05 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: [] 

2018-08-15 10:38:05 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened 2018-08-15 10:38:05 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min) 

2018-08-15 10:38:05 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023 

2018-08-15 10:38:06 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://accounts.google.com/ManageAccount> from <GET https://accounts.google.com> 

2018-08-15 10:38:07 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount&followup=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount> from <GET https://accounts.google.com/ManageAccount> 

2018-08-15 10:38:09 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount&followup=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount> (referer: None) 

**inside parse**

https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount&followup=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount 

2018-08-15 10:38:09 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (405) <POST https://accounts.google.com/> (referer: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount&followup=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount) 

**inside log_password**
https://accounts.google.com/ 

2018-08-15 10:38:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <POST https://accounts.google.com/> (referer: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount&followup=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount)

    Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/PathakUmesh/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3env-piKhfpsf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)   File "google_login.py", line 79, in log_password
        callback=self.after_login)]   File "/Users/PathakUmesh/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3env-piKhfpsf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/form.py", line 48, in from_response
        form = _get_form(response, formname, formid, formnumber, formxpath)   File "/Users/PathakUmesh/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3env-piKhfpsf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/form.py", line 77, in _get_form
        raise ValueError("No <form> element found in %s" % response) ValueError: No <form> element found in <405 https://accounts.google.com/> 

2018-08-15 10:38:10 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished) 
2018-08-15 10:38:10 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats: {'downloader/request_bytes': 1810,  'downloader/request_count': 4,  'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,  'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,  'downloader/response_bytes': 357598,  'downloader/response_count': 4,  'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,  'downloader/response_status_count/302': 2,  'downloader/response_status_count/405': 1,  'finish_reason': 'finished',  'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 15, 4, 53, 10, 164911),  'log_count/DEBUG': 5,  'log_count/ERROR': 1,  'log_count/INFO': 7,  'memusage/max': 41132032,  'memusage/startup': 41132032,  'request_depth_max': 1,  'response_received_count': 2,  'scheduler/dequeued': 4,  'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,  'scheduler/enqueued': 4,  'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,  'spider_exceptions/ValueError': 1,  'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 15, 4, 53, 5, 463699)}

2018-08-15 10:38:10 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 405 means that URL doesn't accept the HTTP method, in your case POST generated at `parse`.

Google default login page is much more complex than simple POST form heavily using JS and Ajax under the hood. To login using Scrapy you have use https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?nojavascript=1 as start URL instead.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks @mizhgun

Comment: You're welcome. If it is what you needed please accept the answer